# Create fully-typed cloudformation JSON in typescript in runtime

Tags: typescript, aws-cloudformation

I'm developing a server-side TypeScript application that receives a user request, and create AWS resources depending on the parameters in the request.

To create AWS resources, I use CloudFormation (CFn). That is, my application assembles JSON CFn template upon a user request, and sends it to AWS by using aws-sdk.

The problem is that there seems to be no reliable way to write JSON template in a type-safed way. (In my TypeScript code, the CFn template has "any" type, which is not safe).

Although there is third-party tool to validate CFn templates, I don't want to use them because they may not catch up the latest CFn specifications.

Another option I came up with was AWS CDK, but it is a command line tool, and it does not support runtime execution.

Any smart solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with writing a cdk utility using cdk construct for creating resources and then generating dynamic templates , now the same dynamic template can be feeded to service endpoint or ansible, which will deploy resources at cloud provider.

Also aws cdk can be utilized in coding format, where one can develop stack as per the requirement and then same can be imported to default app.py, where you can execute it directly and generate dynamic templates, also it can be passed a param to dump json data to particular folder.

This is one of way of using aws cdk python! hope it could be of reference in typescript!
Reference : https://unbiased-coder.com/setup-aws-cdk-python/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to use this package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudform

We have used it in the past with success.
The great thing about this package is, that you can simply regenerate your types to be up-to-date to latest cloudformation specifications.

Just take a look at this file to see how generating works:
https://github.com/bright/cloudform/blob/master/packages/cloudform-types/generator/generator.ts